# Qt C++ class data json serialization

Tags: c++, qt

I have custom class Person. It looks like below.

```
class Person : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(int phoneNumber READ phoneNumber WRITE setPhoneNumber)
    Q_PROPERTY(ChildPerson* childData MEMBER m_childData )
  public:
    Person(){
        m_name = "Flavio";
        m_phoneNumber = 123456;
        m_childData = new ChildPerson();
}
    ~Person(){}

  private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_phoneNumber;
    ChildPerson* m_childData ;
};

class ChildPerson: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(int phoneNumber READ phoneNumber WRITE setPhoneNumber)
  public:
    ChildPerson(){
        m_name = "Flavio";
        m_phoneNumber = 123456;
}
    ~ChildPerson(){}

  private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_phoneNumber;
};
```

I need to save the data of class Person in json form. Whenever I print using qjsondocument m_childData  return "null".

Please let me know if you have any examples or simple ways to recommend.

Comment: I an recommend you to use the nlohmann lib for json in c++

Comment: Person's contructor run in an infinited loop ?

Comment: I think you have an infinite recursion in your constructor.

Comment: @Alexandre Oh, sorry. I change the recursion

Comment: You probably need to produce a [mcve] to get any help solving this.

Comment: Show your attempt of serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add functions to translate your objects into JSON objects.

```
QJsonObject Person::toJson() const
{
    QJsonObject obj;
    obj["name"] = m_name;
    obj["phone"] = m_phoneNumber;
    if (m_childData)
        obj["child"] = m_childData.toJson();
    return obj;
}

QJsonObject ChildPerson::toJson() const
{
    QJsonObject obj;
    obj["name"] = m_name;
    obj["phone"] = m_phoneNumber;
    return obj;
}
```

Then create the JSON like that:

```
QJsonDocument doc;
doc.setObject(myPerson.toJson());
QByteArray data = doc.toJson();

QFile file("save.json");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(data);
file.close();
```

A few remarks:

- If the child is a person, you should try to have the same class for both to avoid duplicating code.
- Probably you could have several children? If yes, using a vector (QList/QVector) of pointers is better. The children could be added by a function instead of being created in the constructor of the parent.
- The phone number should rather be a string than an int, as an int cannot hold 0's at the beginning, and these 0's matter.

To read a Person back from the file, it could look like this:

```
Person myPerson;

QFile file("save.json");
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QByteArray content = file.readAll();
    file.close();

    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(content); // use 2nd argument here to get the parsing error in case the input JSON is malformed
    QJsonObject personJson = doc.object();

    myPerson.fromJson(personJson);
}


void Person::fromJson(const QJsonObject& obj) const
{
    m_name = obj.value("name").toString();
    m_phoneNumber = obj.value("phone").toInt();
    if (obj.contains("child")
    {
        m_childData = new ChildPerson();
        m_childData.fromJson(obj.value("child").toObject());
    }
}

void ChildPerson::fromJson(const QJsonObject& obj) const
{
    m_name = obj.value("name").toString();
    m_phoneNumber = obj.value("phone").toInt(); // or toString()
}
```

More remarks:

- The fromJson() function should rather return a bool: true if the JSON contained the expected data, false otherwise. You can check whether a field exists in the JSON object with contains(QString key).

Comment: Thank you a lot. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How can i read "save.json" and put data to myPerson ?

Comment: Thanks for commenting on the read function. In addition I should have several children as you would expect. I want to use Qlist, but I don't know how. Can you add a read/write method using Qlist?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is excellent. I was however a bit fed up of serializing/deserializing that way, so I implemented something quicker. This is how I defined the classes you proposed:

```
L_BEGIN_CLASS(ChildPerson)
L_RW_PROP_AS(QString, name, "Flavio")
L_RW_PROP_AS(int, phoneNumber, 123456)
L_END_CLASS

L_BEGIN_CLASS(Person)
L_RW_PROP_AS(QString, name, "Flavio")
L_RW_PROP_AS(ChildPerson*, childData, nullptr)
L_END_CLASS
```

This is how I serialize:

```
QJsonObject json = LSerializer().serialize<Person>(person.data());
```

and deserialize:

```
QScopedPointer<Person> person(LDeserializer<Person>().deserialize(json));
```

Here you can find the project: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqobjectserializer.